# C# web api demora mucho tiempo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dotnetcore, asp.net-core-5.0

porfavor necesito ayuda con este problema que tengo hace casi 1 mes. Tengo un cliente el cual consulta mi api, este cliente tiene solo un terminal el cual consulta la api.
El problema es q me dice q mi api a veces demora mas de 20 segundos, lo cual es el tiempo máximo de espera de su terminal.
Para esto decidí cambiar mi api de esta forma agregando este codigo :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Datatransaction> PostDatatransaction(Datatransaction datatransaction)
    {
        string ruta = @"C:\Sistcomerci\JsonApi\";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ruta + DateTime.Now.Minute + "-" + DateTime.Now.Second + "-" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond, "prueba");
```

como pueden ver, cambie mi metodo de asincrono a sincrono y agregé una linea de codigo la cual me crea un archivo de texto para saber el tiempo en el q se ejecuta mi api.
Luego comparo el tiempo en el q se creo ese archivo de texto con el tiempo de respuesta q me da mi log del iis.
Mi sorpresa es q en mi método POST no se da la demora nunca.
Por lo que ya no se cual podría ser el problema.

Comment: Esto ocurre a veces, o el 100% de las veces? Qué dicen tus pruebas? Es posible que te compartan el request y response utilizando Fiddler o Postman? De esta manera puedes ver la hora de los requests y el tiempo que tomó tu server en responder; así puedes saber si es la implementación tuya o de ellos.

Comment: Considera utilizar `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` para medir el tiempo de respuesta de tu servidor desde que entra el request hasta que sale; y lo escribes en tu archivo de texto.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigos, de las 30 transacciones q se hacen al día, solo pasa 1 vez.

Comment: @Arriel probare eso, gracias

Comment: Esa única vez que ocurre, es la primera del día? De ser así, tal vez [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387790/why-asp-net-web-api-response-gets-too-much-time) te ayude

Comment: Me suena que es problema de lentitud en la red, puedes probar haciendo ping desde fuera a tu server o desde la maquina del cliente a cualquier pagina de internet dependiendo del ping te podrías dar una idea de que tan lentas son las conexiones.

Comment: Otra sugerencia que te puedo hacer es hostear tu api en otro server a ver si mejora la lentitud, nose si lo tengas en un server propio, pero podrias probar por ejemplo en https://www.interserver.net/webhosting/windows-hosting.html que cuesta como 8 dolarese al mes o tal vez rentar un VPS en iozoom https://www.iozoom.com/  10 dls al mes, o si ya tiene mas para gastar puede ser AZURE aunque puedes tener 12 meses de servicios gratis en azure

Comment: Mira yo te recomendaría que actives los 12 meses gratis de azure y crees una app service